# How to change cell based on another cell value on Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a Google sheet got more than 10,000 rows, so I want to change cell value based on another cell, e.g column B has 200 rows out of this 200 rows there are 74 rows have value 910, I want to change column C based on column B so if column B has 910 value change column C value to "Hail" on the same row that has 910 on B column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

paste this into **C1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B=910; "Hail"; ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly :)), but I can't use this formula multiple times, like I used "=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B=910; "Hail"; ))" in C1, I want to use it again with another value like "=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B=850; "Co-oers"; ))" but it gave me  erro "Error Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C2.", you will really help me with that..

Comment: try like this in C1: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B=910; "Hail"; IF(B1:B=850; "Co-oers"; )))`

Comment: Bro, It's really awkward but I want to say I love you :D